# TypeError on split()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

I am trying to hide elements based on whether the user has added the class numbers to the database which I am retrieving through json data. If all the class numbers are present on the component I want to hide it.

At the moment I keep getting this error:
`TypeError: $(...).data(...).split is not a function`

```
export function VisaToggleComponent() {
let json = {
    visa_subclass:[462,500,801]
};

let elements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-visa-hide]');

console.log(elements);

$(elements).each(function() {
    let data = json.visa_subclass,
        target = $(this).data('visa-hide').split(',').map(Number);

    console.log(target);

    for (let i in data) {
        let val = data[i];
        let index = target.indexOf(val);

        if(index > -1) {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    }
});
}
```

Comment: can you see the value returned by `$(this).data('visa-hide')` ?

Comment: The value returned for `target` is `462,500,800`

Comment: As integers not a string

Answer (score 0):

`split` is a method of the `String` object. Since you're getting

> TypeError: $(...).data(...).split is not a function

It means `$(this).data('visa-hide')` is not a string.

To be honest, I didnt try to understand your code, however if you think `$(this).data('visa-hide')` is *string-like* data type you have to change `$(this).data('visa-hide').split(',')` to  `String.prototype.split.call($(this).data('visa-hide'), ',')`

Comment: `$(this).data('visa-hide')` is a string but then I convert it to an integer using `map()` if I remember correctly.